# Report Parameters Missing in VS2010?

Tags: reportviewer

This may be a silly question but where did they bury report parameters in VS2010?

It was easy in 2005/2008.  Go to report menu then select report parameters.  Now I can't for the life of me find it anywhere!

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the way to do is as follows:

1. Open your report.
2. Click on the 'View' menu
3. At the bottom, select 'Report Data'

Or you can hit ctrl+alt+D

In the view pane that pops up there is a node called 'Parameters' where you can add new report parameters.

Why is 'Report Data' not under the 'Report' menu?  Good question, such are the mysteries of Microsoft.